# Parsing an array of comma-numbers obtained from an input dialog

Tags: java

I made this nice bit of code that I can insert into any of my projects requiring user input. It seems quite long for what it does and I would love some incite as to how I can do this more efficiently i.e. fewer lines of code.

I love to make my code elegant, but I don't see how to do it any better.

```
    String x = (JOptionPane.showInputDialog(". Each patamater should be separated with a ',' and without spaces. (eg. 1,2,3)") + ",");
    int w = 0, a = 0, y = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++)
    {
        if(x.charAt(i) == ',')
        {
            w++;
        }
    }
    Double[] z = new Double[w];
    for(int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++)
    {
        if(x.charAt(i) == ',')
        {
            z[a] = Double.parseDouble(x.substring((y + 1), i));
            y = i;
            a++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Fewer lines of code does not mean that your program is more efficient.

Comment: @Pazis: Whats the distinction?

Comment: @lukeb28 Calling a function like `orderEveryDogInTheWorld();` will take more time than calling `int x = 0;` and `x = x + 1;`, even though the second example is two lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest next way:

```
    String x = (JOptionPane.showInputDialog(". Each patamater should be separated with a ',' and without spaces. (eg. 1,2,3)") + ",");
    String[] split = x.split(",");
    Double[] z = new Double[split.length];
    int i = 0;
    for (String s : split) {
        if(s.trim().isEmpty()){
            continue;
        }
        try {
            z[i++] = Double.valueOf(s.trim());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

1)`split()` instead of loop for *','*

2)validate spaces

read more about [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class and it's functions.

Comment: I've never seen split, s.trim, or .isEmpty. Would you mind running through how these functions work? I prefer comprehension to memorization.

Comment: @lukeb28 It will sink in more (requiring less memorization) if you hunt for them in the docs.